# Set function parameter types in Go

Tags: go

I'm a complete beginner to the Go programming language, and I'm trying to define the parameter types of a Go function called `addStuff` that simply adds two integers and returns their sum, but I see the following error when I try to compile the function:

```
prog.go:6: undefined: a
prog.go:6: undefined: b
prog.go:7: undefined: a
prog.go:7: undefined: b
prog.go:7: too many arguments to return
prog.go:11: addStuff(4, 5) used as value
```

Here's the code that produced this compiler error:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func addStuff(a, b){
    return a+b
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello," + strconv.Itoa(addStuff(4,5)))
}
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what is the correct way to set the types of parameters in Go?

Comment: Considering the amount of duck-typed languages there are, this is (in my opinion) a valid question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
func addStuff(a int, b int) int {
    return a+b
}
```

This will make `a` and `b` parameters of type `int`, and have the function return an `int`. An alternative is `func addStuff(a, b int) int` which will also make both `a` and `b` parameters of type `int`.

I highly recommend [*A Tour of Go*](http://tour.golang.org/#1) which teaches the basics of Go.

Comment: this can also be written as `func addStuff(a, b int) int`

Comment: I would edit your answer only to fix a typo or so, never to change your idea. And yes, I read your answer in full before writing my previous comment. You're confusing 'alternative' with 'idiomatic code'.

Comment: +1 to offset the -1; this is the same syntax shown in the tour on the languages own website. It may not be the "most" idiomatic, but it's correct, and not so onerous that the language's website that they can't wait until the next screen to show the shorter alternative.